# How to get rid of this Constructor error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've taken 2 OOP C# classes, but now our professor is switching over to c++. So, to get used to c++, I wrote this very simple program, but I keep getting this error:

`error C2533: 'Counter::{ctor}' : constructors not allowed a return type`

I'm confused, because I believe I have coded my default constructor right.

Here's my code for the simple counter class:

```
class Counter
{
private:
int count;
bool isCounted;

public:
Counter();
bool IsCountable();
void IncrementCount();
void DecrementCount();
int GetCount();
}

Counter::Counter()
{
count = 0;
isCounted = false;
}

bool Counter::IsCountable()
{
if (count == 0)
    return false;
else
    return true;
}

void Counter::IncrementCount()
{
count++;
isCounted = true;
}

void Counter::DecrementCount()
{
count--;
isCounted = true;
}

int Counter::GetCount()
{
return count;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not specifying a return type. Or am I somehow?

Comment: Please read up on *initialization lists*: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=172

Comment: IsCountable can be simplified to `return count == 0`.  
BTW, why do you have a member `isCounter` if it is never read (used)?

Comment: Correction, that should be *why do you have `isCounted`...*

Comment: @Georg: ***Member** initialization lists*. Important distinction, and a common error.

Comment: @Tomalak: So the **linked resource** says... it really should be clear in this context...

Comment: @Georg: (a) The linked resource is not authoritative; (b) as I said, it's a common error; (c) what is clear to you or I is not clear to someone who has never heard of either kind of initializer. [edit: the linked resource _does_ name them properly; so then so should your comment!]

Comment: @Tomalak: Sure, next time i'll link a draft standard as introductory material... Just look at the date of the comments here and move on ;)

Comment: @George: Just include the word "member" and everyone will be happy. :) The comment date is not at all relevant: regardless of when you posted it, it's there for the entire internet to learn falsehoods from for all time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot the semi-colon at the end of your class definition. Without the semi-colon, the compiler thinks the class you just defined is the return type for the constructor following it in the source file. This is a common C++ error to make, memorize the solution, you'll need it again.

```
class Counter
{
private:
int count;
bool isCounted;

public:
Counter();
bool IsCountable();
void IncrementCount();
void DecrementCount();
int GetCount();
};
```

Comment: wow. That was it. In c++ you need semicolons after your class definitions?

Comment: This is where GCC shines a bit - you get the diagnostic "note: (perhaps a semicolon is missing after the definition of 'Counter')"

Comment: @Alex Yes - just like you need them after struct definitions in C.

Comment: Between the missing semicolon end the missing namespace end... sometimes you really are in for a world of pain... and the fact that it crosses files (with the include mechanism) isn't really charming either :/

Comment: @Neil: In every case? MSVC does the same in some cases, but it obviously depends on the context. Sometimes, it's not able to guess that this was a possible explanation for the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end your class declaration with a semicolon.

```
class Counter
{
private:
int count;
bool isCounted;

public:
Counter();
bool IsCountable();
void IncrementCount();
void DecrementCount();
int GetCount();
} ;
```